# What compilation flags I need to use to get this `file` output?

Tags: c, gcc, mips, embedded-linux, mips32

I want to compile some code to run on an embedded Linux w/ MIPS arch. But I can't get my MIPS cross compiler (`mips-linux-gnu-gcc`) to compile my hello-world file correctly. I mean, it is compiling without errors. It just doesn't run on my embedded device.

I downloaded a sample executable from the device (which is proved to be running correctly obviously) and running `file` this is the output I get:

```
ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, stripped
```

But when I compile my code with

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc main.c
```

`file`'s result on my compiled file is:

```
ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=..., not stripped
```

I've tried adding `-mips1 -mfp32` to the compilation command but still the output isn't what I want:

```
ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=..., not stripped
```

What flags do I need to use for the compiler to compile my program correctly? Or do I need a completely different compiler?
I suspect it's only flags but I don't know which. I suspect that the problem is that I get MIPS32 instead of MIPS-I.

Comment: _It just doesn't run on my embedded device._  -- How exactly doesn't it run, what are the error messages, if there are any?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how `file` outputs what it does for your files. Could you please post the output of `hexdump -C <file> | head` here for both files?